# Find pair of adjacent prime numbers in a two-dimensional array

Tags: performance, c, array, primes

Does anybody know how to find pair of adjacent prime numbers in two-dimensional array, quicker than this? I'm talking especially about this part which looks for adjacent numbers not about function finding  prime numbers or anything else in the code.

```
//looking for first prime number of pair
for(w=0; w<5; w++)
            {      
for(k=0; k<5; k++)
            {    
if(is_prime(tab[w][k])==1)
            { 
//looking for second number if pair in indices with are only higher then the first prime number
    for(w2=w; w2<5; w2++)
            {
    for(k2=k; k2<5; k2++)
            {
    if(is_prime(tab[w2][k2])==1)
            {
//setting conditions for adjacent number (which isnt the same number as the first)
    if(abs(w-w2)<=1&&abs(k-k2)<=1&&((w==w2)+(k==k2))!=2)
//putting adjacent prime pairs one after another into second array
    {tab2[i]=w; tab2[i+1]=k; tab2[i+2]=w2; tab2[i+3]=k2; i+=4;}
            }}}}}}
```

````
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int is_prime(int);

//function checking if number is prime

int is_prime(int x)
{
int count=0, i;
if(x<2) return 0;

 for(i=2; i<x; i++)
   {if((x%i)==0) count++;}

if(count==0) 
return 1;
else
return 0;
 }


int main()
{int k, w, tab[5][5], k2, w2;
printf("Input: ");

//inputting data into two-dimensional array
for(w=0; w<5; w++)
         {
for(k=0; k<5; k++)
         {
 if(scanf("%d", &tab[w][k])==0) 
   {
printf("Incorrect input"); return 1;
   }     }}


int tab2[1000], i=0;

//looking for first prime number of pair
for(w=0; w<5; w++)
            {      
for(k=0; k<5; k++)
            {    
if(is_prime(tab[w][k])==1)
            { 
//looking for second number if pair in indices with are only higher then the first prime number
    for(w2=w; w2<5; w2++)
            {
    for(k2=k; k2<5; k2++)
            {
    if(is_prime(tab[w2][k2])==1)
            {
//setting conditions for adjacent number (which isnt the same number as the first)
    if(abs(w-w2)<=1&&abs(k-k2)<=1&&((w==w2)+(k==k2))!=2)
//putting adjacent prime pairs one after another into second array
    {tab2[i]=w; tab2[i+1]=k; tab2[i+2]=w2; tab2[i+3]=k2; i+=4;}
            }}}}}}
//i is used also as counter of pairs
w=i; 
//printing number of pairs
printf("%d\n", i/4);
//printing the pairs
for(i=0; i<w; i+=4)
printf("%d %d %d %d\n", tab2[i], tab2[i+1], tab2[i+2], tab2[i+3]);

    return 0;
}


```
````

Comment: You should do some reasonable and consistent indentation clarifying the several code blocks' scope. There's a number of styles you can choose from. But how it's like just now, that's not matching any of these. BTW there are even tools like _astyle_ to support you with this.

Comment: Did you write this or did you find it elsewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Your function `is_prime` is extremely inefficient perfomance wise called every time you want to check for prime numbers (especially for larger ranges).
You're going to loop over all the values and check every time it's called.

You should rather consider to implement a memoizing algorithm like the [Sieve of Erasthotenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to check for prime numbers in 1st place to improve the overall performance.